# Can I get my Mexican wife from Mexico to the USA while doing the I-130?

Tags: usa

I paid Rapidvisa.com for a premium account and will be starting my I-130 paper work for my wife in Mexico to come to the USA. Is there anyway to get her here as soon as possible while I am doing the paper work? I prefer not to wait 6 to 8 months.

Answer (score 3):

She can try to get a visitor visa to come visit briefly and leave the US on time. She would need to show ties to Mexico to the visa officer and convince the officer that she would return to Mexico and not, for example, apply for Adjustment of Status during her stay in the US (which she is eligible to do at any time if she changes her mind while in the US). Keep in mind that Mexicans are often denied US visas and it may be especially difficult for her due to difficulty to overcome the presumption of immigrant intent in her case.